# dup( fileno( stdin ) ) and then spawn of 32 threads -> I/O errors

Tags: c, thread-safety, fread, file-descriptor, dup

I've written Zsh module. There I have a builtin – function mapped to Zsh command. This function duplicates its stdin file descriptor:

```
/* Duplicate standard input */
oconf->stream = fdopen( dup( fileno( stdin ) ), "r" );
```

Then a thread is spawned that obtains `oconf` structure. In that thread, I do:

```
errno = 0;

/* Read e.g. 5 characters, putting them after previous portion */
int count = fread( buf + index, 1, read_size, oconf->stream );
/* Ensure that our whole data is a string - null terminated */
buf[ index + count ] = '\0';

if ( errno ) {
    fprintf( oconf->err, "Read error (descriptor: %d): %s\n", fileno( oconf->stream ), strerror( errno ) >
}
```

If I spawn 32 threads in zsh:

```
for (( i=1; i<=32; i ++ )); do
    ls -R /Users/myuser/Documents | mybuiltin -A myhash_$i $i
done
```

Then 2-3 threads have the I/O error reported from the above `fprintf()`, e.g.:

> Read error (descriptor: 7): Input/output error
>
> Read error (descriptor: 5): Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> Read error (descriptor: 14): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Debugger says that those threads, after multiple (5-20) fread() repetitions, get blocked in kernel's `__read_nocancel()`. So something really bad is going on with the file descriptor.

Otherwise this works. The pipe correctly passes data from `ls -R`, it gets read by the custom builtin. So where's the hazard? How come that `dup()` performed in main thread results in something unreadable to `fread()`? I could have doubts if I would do `dup()` in secondary thread. But I keep that only in safe place – main thread, to then pass ready `FILE *` stream to secondary thread. Also tried with POSIX `open()`, `read()` and `close()`, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing `errno` incorrectly.  You should only check `errno` if a function that sets it has reported an error.  No function in the standard C or POSIX library ever sets `errno` to zero.  And functions may set `errno` to non-zero without reporting an error.

For example, on Solaris, it used to be the case (and probably still is the case) that after write operations, `errno == ENOTTY` if the file stream was not a terminal (e.g. redirected to a file or pipe).  There wasn't a problem; the output device wasn't a terminal so a terminal-only operation failed, setting `errno` to `ENOTTY`.

You currently have:

```
/* Read e.g. 5 characters, putting them after previous portion */
int count = fread( buf + index, 1, read_size, oconf->stream );
/* Ensure that our whole data is a string - null terminated */
buf[ index + count ] = '\0';

if ( errno ) {
    fprintf( oconf->err, "Read error (descriptor: %d): %s\n", fileno( oconf->stream ), strerror( errno ));
}
```

You need to use something more like:

```
int count = fread(buf + index, 1, read_size, oconf->stream);
if (count == 0)
{
    /* EOF or error — this might be a time to use feof() or ferror() */
    fprintf(oconf->err, "Read error (descriptor: %d): %s\n", fileno(oconf->stream), strerror(errno));
    …flow control?…
}
else
    buf[index + count] = '\0';
```

You probably need some other flow-of-control details (return or break or set flag) in the EOF and error path; it isn't clear from your quoted fragment what might be appropriate.